# Pandas fillna with np.select

Tags: pandas, numpy, fillna

I have the dataframe ('data') which looks like this:

| index | competitor | region | sku | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | A | M | 01 | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 001 | A | M | 01 | 2022-01-02 | 099 |
| 002 | A | M | 01 | 2022-01-03 | 099 |
| 003 | A | B | 02 | 2022-01-01 | 101 |
| 004 | A | B | 02 | 2022-01-02 | 100 |
| 005 | A | B | 02 | 2022-01-03 | 101 |

Columns 'competitor', 'region', 'sku', 'date' DO NOT contain nans, but 'price' does.

I want to do the following:

- ffill prices for every competitor, for every region, for every sku;
- bfill prices for every competitor, for every region, for every sku;
- if all prices for competitor, for region, for sku are nans for all dates, then do nothing.

For loops/ apply is obviously too slow, so I decided to go with np.select:

```
prev_comp = data['competitor'].shift(1)
prev_reg = data['region'].shift(1)
prev_art = data['sku'].shift(1)

conditions = [
    (data['price'].isna()) & (data['price'].shift(1).notna()) & (data['competitor'].values == prev_comp) & (data['region'].values == prev_reg) & (data['sku'].values == prev_art),
    (data['price'].isna()) & (data['price'].shift(-1).notna()) & (data['competitor'].values != prev_comp) & (data['region'].values != prev_reg) & (data['sku'].values != prev_art),
    (data['price'].shift(1).notna()) & (data['price'].shift(-1).notna())
]

choices = [
    data.fillna(method='ffill'), 
    data.fillna(method='bfill'),
    data
]

data = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
> shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (3930229,) and arg 1 with
> shape (3930229, 10).

The error referres to the shapes of conditions (3930229,) and choices (3930229, 10), but I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function for forward and back filling missing values, if not exist non missing value per groups are returned `NaN`s:

```
f = lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()
df['price'] = df.groupby(['competitor','region','sku'])['price'].transform(f)
```

Comment: Dear jezrael, your code works, but it takes around 10 minutes. Np.select makes all its calculations in less than a minute. Do you see a way to improve my solution?

Comment: @frogseer - I test your code, not working for me. Btw you need replace `groupby.ffill, groupby.bfill` by `np.select` ? I think not possible. Maybe some really complicated numpy solution should exist, but I am sure `np.select` is wrong way.

Comment: @frogseer - try replace last column to `100, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 101` for see ouput `[  0. 100.   0.   0.   0.   0.]` if use `choices = [
    data['price'].fillna(method='ffill'), 
    data['price'].fillna(method='bfill'),
    data['price']
]`